# Debug JSP using Eclipse and JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging, jboss

I need to debug JSP files using Eclipse and JBoss. I have a very big project. I have made remote debug. I configured JBoss and created debug configuration in Eclipse. If i put breakpoint in some place inside java class - everything works well and execution stops at this breakpoint. But then i'm trying to do the same thing inside JSP file execution doesn't stop at my breakpoint. What should i do to make JSP breakpoints work?

After building and compilation i'm getting ear file.

I'm using Eclipse Luna for Java EE developers and JBoss Application Server 7.1.1.

I'm setting breakpoints on java code inside jsp file.
JBoss starts with with bat file:

```
@echo off
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem JBoss Bootstrap Script for Windows
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem $Id$

@if not "%ECHO%" == ""  echo %ECHO%
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
  set "DIRNAME=%~dp0%"
) else (
  set DIRNAME=.\
)

rem Read an optional configuration file.
if "x%STANDALONE_CONF%" == "x" (
   set "STANDALONE_CONF=%DIRNAME%standalone.conf.bat"
)
if exist "%STANDALONE_CONF%" (
   echo Calling "%STANDALONE_CONF%"
   call "%STANDALONE_CONF%" %*
) else (
   echo Config file not found "%STANDALONE_CONF%"
)

pushd %DIRNAME%..
set "RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if "x%JBOSS_HOME%" == "x" (
  set "JBOSS_HOME=%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%"
)

pushd "%JBOSS_HOME%"
set "SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if "%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%" NEQ "%SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME%" (
    echo WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.
)

set DIRNAME=

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
  set "PROGNAME=%~nx0%"
) else (
  set "PROGNAME=standalone.bat"
)

rem Setup JBoss specific properties
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=6687,server=y,suspend=n
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME%
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.ignoreTCL=true
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dwin.debug=0
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms256m -Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/security/cacerts
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\

if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
  set  JAVA=java
  echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
  echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
) else (
  set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
)

if not "%PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS%" == "true" (
  rem Add -client to the JVM options, if supported (32 bit VM), and not overriden
  echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I \-server > nul
  if errorlevel == 1 (
    "%JAVA%" -client -version 2>&1 | findstr /I /C:"Client VM" > nul
    if not errorlevel == 1 (
      set "JAVA_OPTS=-client %JAVA_OPTS%"
    )
  )

  rem Add compressed oops, if supported (64 bit VM), and not overriden
  echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I "\-XX:\-UseCompressedOops \-client" > nul
  if errorlevel == 1 (
    "%JAVA%" -XX:+UseCompressedOops -version > nul 2>&1
    if not errorlevel == 1 (
      set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UseCompressedOops %JAVA_OPTS%"
    )
  )

  rem Add tiered compilation, if supported (64 bit VM), and not overriden
  echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I "\-XX:\-TieredCompilation \-client" > nul
  if errorlevel == 1 (
    "%JAVA%" -XX:+TieredCompilation -version > nul 2>&1
    if not errorlevel == 1 (
      set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+TieredCompilation %JAVA_OPTS%"
    )
  )
)

rem Find jboss-modules.jar, or we can't continue
if exist "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" (
    set "RUNJAR=%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar"
) else (
  echo Could not locate "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar".
  echo Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
  goto END
)

rem Setup JBoss specific properties

rem Setup the java endorsed dirs
set JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed

rem Set default module root paths
if "x%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" == "x" (
  set  "JBOSS_MODULEPATH=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules"
)

rem Set the standalone base dir
if "x%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%" == "x" (
  set  "JBOSS_BASE_DIR=%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone"
)
rem Set the standalone log dir
if "x%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%" == "x" (
  set  "JBOSS_LOG_DIR=%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%\log"
)
rem Set the standalone configuration dir
if "x%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%" == "x" (
  set  "JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%/configuration"
)

echo ===============================================================================
echo.
echo   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
echo.
echo   JBOSS_HOME: %JBOSS_HOME%
echo.
echo   JAVA: %JAVA%
echo.
echo   JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
echo.

:RESTART
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^
 "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%\boot.log" ^
 "-Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%/logging.properties" ^
    -jar "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" ^
    -mp "%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" ^
    -jaxpmodule "javax.xml.jaxp-provider" ^
     org.jboss.as.standalone ^
    -Djboss.home.dir="%JBOSS_HOME%" ^
     %*

if ERRORLEVEL 10 goto RESTART

:END
if "x%NOPAUSE%" == "x" pause

:END_NO_PAUSE
```

I'm not using JBoss tools, but i'm reading how to use them now.
I can't ddebug before putting it in EAR file because it's a huge project and everything depends on everything.

Comment: Why not use firebug for the javascript part in Firefox or the console in Chrome ? I use this mixed mode alot and it works well. (Remember in Chrome CTRL-P to find a js file is a time saver).

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/how-can-i-debug-a-jsp

Comment: @JFPicard, i need to debug Java code, not javascript code.

Comment: @Rahul, it's about IDEA not Eclipse and i'm getting ear file and can't use this case.

Comment: Where are you setting your breakpoints? How is JBoss being launched? Are you using the JBoss Tools? Can you ddebug it before putting it in the EAR file?

Comment: @nitind, answered in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this trouble too. I am using Eclipse Luna + JBoss Tools (Luna) + JBoss 7.1.1 Final. JBoss will be started from Eclipse in debugging modus. But no one breakepoint is working in JSP, only in class files.
I found that it is a bug of JBoss 7.1.x (https://developer.jboss.org/message/723813)

I downloaded EAP 6.1 (old name - JBoss 7.2.0) - it is working perfect with JBoss Tools (Luna) 4.2.3 Final.